# Opening not existing ftp folders via ftp.cwd() in python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have such a case - I'm working with FTP with help of `ftplib` in Python.

I have a list of ftp pathes, that I need to check for existence. I was going to check it with `ftp.cwd()` method + `try\except`, - when exception is raised, folder doesn't exist. But `pwd` of some folders, which don't exist in fact (I check it with my `FtpZilla`) return `250 CWD command successful` and in `ftp.nlst()` I get list of folder on one or more folders above.

According to `FileZilla` and `ftp.nlst("order\dvd\pictures")` there are only "games" folder.
But if I make `ftp.cwd("order\dvd\pictures\cars\ferari\")`, It returns `250 CWD command successful` and `ftp.nstl()` is equal to `ftp.nlst("order\dvd\pictures")`.

Such case is not in every folder, - when trying to enter some non-existing folders, I get `No such file or directory` which is right.

Maybe there are some "hidden" folders on ftp that cannot be found by neither `FileZilla`, nor `ftp.nslt()`, but can be reached by `fpt.cwd()`?

Comment: Is this a public ftp server?

Comment: It is private, i.e. I need to enter host\login\pass to access it.

Comment: It's gonna be difficult to give an answer without being able to reproduce the problem.